# Imprimir o conteúdo da div com css

Tags: jquery

Consegui com a ajuda do `Stackoverflow` montar um script para impressão de um documento, agora estou com um segundo problema, o script abre a página de impressão sem a formatação do `css`.
Vi um exemplo aqui mesmo mas não consegui alterar de acordo com o que preciso, vi isso aqui:

[Exemplo de css sendo carregado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753420/jquery-print-function-to-print-div-content-with-css)

No exemplo o css está sendo carregado pelo script, mas no meu exemplo tenho isso:

```
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {   
    var conteudo = document.getElementById('conteudo').innerHTML,
    impressao = window.open('about:blank');
    impressao.document.write(conteudo);
    impressao.window.print();
    impressao.window.close();
};
```

Como posso carregar o css no meu exemplo?

Comment: E onde está o CSS? Você quer adiciona-lo a uma _popup_ aberta? É um bloco de código CSS ou um arquivo?

Comment: Olá @KaduAmaral, o css é chamado em minha página sendo inserido por esse comando: <link href="../_comp/externos/bootstrap3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: Esse código `<link href="...">` está dentro do elemento `div#conteudo`? **[Exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/buko3xcj/)**

Comment: Não, ele é chamado no head, o exemplo que você passou executa, mostra o preview formatado mas a impressão não fica configurada.

Comment: Pois então, tenha em mente que `impressao.document` é um novo documento (um site totalmente diferente e independente para o navegador). Coloque uma cópia do código `<link href="...">` dentro do elemento `div#conteudo` ou tente algo como `impressao.document.write('<link href="...">' + conteudo);`.